# iOS "stuck" while erasing

Tags: ios, jailbreak, iphone

I recently decided to start off with a fresh install of iOS due to my springboard crashing often and everything being messed up. I went to `Settings > General > Reset` to reset the device, and it started out OK. Currently, it's been sitting with the spinner icon (The one you get when you power down) for over half an hour with no progress. Is this normal? If not, what should I do? I have an iPhone 5s, 32 GB storage, but only about 6 GB is actually used. The spinner icon isn't frozen, it's still moving.

Comment: Where is your back up ?

Comment: I decided to take my chances and hold down home and power. It turns out - the device shut down and restarted as normal.

Comment: and it is now looking for a back up?, iCloud ect..

Comment: In the reset menu - which did you preform? Erase all Content and Settings?

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen. What you can do is, press and hold the home and power key for 10 seconds. The device will enter recovery mode and now you can connect to itunes and install the iOS operating system from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Reset would erase all data and settings on iPhone, if you have important data and don't want to lose it, you should backup your iPhone before reset. Reset may solve the stuck problem but here i want to recommend another easy and free tool called ReiBoot to fix iPhone stuck problems. You can get the tool from google by searching with "reiboot". 
[image]

Comment: That would require Jailbreak ?

Answer (score 0):

I sense you have a jailbroken iOS device. If your device is jailbroken, then you cannot reset it using the method you used. You have to download the latest iOS firmware version for your device on computer and restore it using iTunes.

It will provide you a complete fresh start. However, before removing anything, make sure to take a backup of your device.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put your iPhone into recovery mode using [RecBoot](http://www.cydiageeks.com/recboot-enter-exit-recovery-mode-iphone.html) and then kick it out should help resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Something went wrong and you can fix it easily. you can try entering into recovery mode and there is a little tool names recboot and you can [download recboot](http://www.cydiatechie.com/143/download-recboot-windows-mac-linux.html/). You can download it for almost all operating systems. This application is a life saver as it can help you get in and out of recovery mode easily without any issues.